# Get list of storage volumes authorized to particular host in SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using /etc/hosts to determine all IP's from my running cluseter.  I can get the VM id's with

```
    for node_ip in ip_list:
    node_ip = ''.join(node_ip)
    id_mask = "mask[id]"
    vm_instance = SL.instance(sl_config).vm.list_instances(mask=id_mask,private_ip=node_ip)
    print vm_instance
```

Now, I'd like to use VM id's in order to get a list of the storage volumes attached to them.  I am looking at using Virtual_Guest, but haven't had luck with

```
 vm_guest = SL.instance(sl_config).vm_guest.findByIpAddress(id=node_ip)
```

How can I access the storage volumes from this ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following mask in your code **allowedNetworkStorage**

e.g:

```
id_mask = "mask[id, allowedNetworkStorage]"
```

It will display information for the storage objects that this Virtual Server has access to