# softlayer get list of 'replica' volumes authorized to a host

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a set of block volumes authorized to a host on datacenter `DC1`. These volumes have been 'replicated' to datacenter `DC2`. The 'replica' volumes (_REP) on `DC2` have been authorized with a host on `DC2`.
Now I want to find out this list of volumes for that given host.

Using **list_instances**() with **allowedNetworkStorage** and **blockDevice** masks as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299496/get-list-of-storage-volumes-authorized-to-particular-host-in-softlayer) does not return the list of '**replica**' volumes. It only lists the volume that were provisioned on `DC2` and authorized for this host.

So, how can I get the list of `'replica'` volumes authorized for the host?

Thanks,
~ Urjit

Answer (score 0):

Please, could you try to use: **allowedNetworkStorageReplicas** instead of **allowedNetworkStorage**, or you can use **both**:

> **Updated**

- **allowedNetworkStorage** returns result, it means that the network
  attached is the storage
- **allowedNetworkStorageReplicas** returns result, it means that the
  network attached is the replication

I verified that the request returns the storage's name (but it means that the replication from the storage is attached), but if you wish to get the storage replication's username, try the following:

e.g:

> id_mask = "mask[id, hostname,
>   allowedNetworkStorageReplicas[replicationPartners[username]]]"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I see that **allowedNetworkStorageReplicas** returns the **original** volume information, not the **replica** volume (_REP). That seems odd, cause the original volume is on a different datacenter and is not (could not be) explicitly authorised with this host. Only the replica (_REP) is authorised with this host.
Is there a way to get the list of volumes that are explicitly authorised with the host?

Comment: You are using this mask: allowedNetworkStorageReplicas, if it returns information, it means that the network attached is a replication from the storage, otherwise it returns an empty result. I believe that you want to retrieve the name, review the **Updated** section in my answer, that's the way to get the storage replication's username

Comment: This is the way, that [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) gets the information, let me know if you have any doubt or comment, I hope it helps